# Add global define for batch Visual Studio build

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, batch-file

I want to make a batch build for my solution. But instead of several configurations, each with different defines, I edit those defines manually in a global header file.

So I have a header with strings like:

```
#define ENABLE_FEATURE_1
//#define ENABLE_FEATURE_2
```

So in order to build all required configurations, I need to comment/uncomment those lines.

Is it able somehow to pass the `/D` option to the build command like in the following?

```
devenv.exe MyProject.sln /build "Release|Win32"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call devenv to compile your project. Take a look at [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-reference).